# poissonc process

Tags: probability

[image]

Not sure what to do for a). 
Would I approach part b) like so $$1 - P(X = 0) = 1 - (\lambda t)^k {e^{-\lambda t}\over k!},\quad k=0,1,2,\ldots$$ 
Thanks.

Comment: You might tell us your own thoughts.  For example, what is the probability that a particular call arrived in the first $30$ minutes given that it arrived in the first $90$?

Comment: You mean that you want someone to write up an answer with _these specific numbers_ for you rather than _read_ what other similar problems ask for and how people answered those, and try and figure it out for yourself?

Comment: @DilipSarwate No. I simply meant that the other problems didn't help me evaluate and understand the problem any better.

Comment: Given the problem statement, (a) is asking for a conditional probability. Do you know how to calculate a conditional probability?

Answer (score 1):

For part a), I was thinking about it (and if someone can verify it that'd be great!) and based off conditional probability $$ Pr(A|B) = \frac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(B)}$$
If we take the rate $\lambda$ to be per 30 minutes (can we do this?) , the probability of B where all 3 calls took place in 90 minutes =  $\left(e^{-3\lambda}\frac{(3\lambda)^{3}}{3!}\right)$

For  $Pr(A\cap B)$ to occur, all 3 calls had to have taken place in the first 30 minutes and none in the next 60 minutes and thus, $Pr(A\cap B) = \left(e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{3}}{3!}\right)\left( e^{-2\lambda}\frac{2\lambda^{0}}{0!}\right)$

What we get is essentially $\binom{3}{3}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{3} = (\frac{1}{3})^{3}$

For part b), would it just be $\binom{3}{1}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{3} = 3 * (\frac{1} {3})^{3}$ ?

Comment: Shifting the timescale for the rate is fine, so this looks good

Comment: I'd do $1-$ a probability that none arrive, in (b)